# How can i trace eating with mouth closed using Google ML Kit

Tags: android-studio, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

Currently i tried to calculate distance between UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM and LOWER_LIP_TOP, and i set the threshold value 23 (Calculated by minimum distance between both UPPER_LIP_BOTTOM and LOWER_LIP_TOP), if current distance go above the THRESHOLD it will show "Eating" but this method is not working when i am eating with my mouth closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment with a couple of things:

1. Take all the points in the mouth as the input and build a second ML classifier model (a single layer fully connected model might work).
2. In addition to above, take input from multiple frames. There maybe additional complication if the frames are not taken in regular intervals.

I am interested in the use-case, can you tell us more?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hoi for this solution, i am trying to control media player when facial value change , i saved every landmark value into an array and now i am trying to use (x,y) coordinate of every contour to control media player, but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, problem is by changing the distance between camera and user, coordinates are changing.